# Get-ItemProperty how to filter installed instances of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using this PowerShell command to get list of installed instances:

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
```

Output:

```
SQLEXPRESS
DBONE
```

The instance SQLEXPRESS is not running, so I would like to exclude it.

Can I filter the value data to get only the DBONE instance?

Comment: Are you always going to be looking for "WEBLABEL" or is that value supposed to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the naive way is just to filter the output to exclude `SQLEXPRESS`:

```
(get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances |where-object {$_ -ne "SQLEXPRESS"}
```

If you need to correlate with the instances that are actually running, you'll need some way of distinguishing them in the `Get-Process` list ... like maybe the username they run under. Or you could use `WMIC` and inspect the startup directory?